# Differentiable function exercise in $B(\mathbf{0},r)$

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $E, F$ normed spaces and Suppose that $g:E\rightarrow F$ is differentiable in every point of $B(\mathbf{0},r)$, that $g(\mathbf0)=\mathbf0$, and that $\|Dg(x)\|\leq\lambda$ for all $x\in B(\mathbf0,r)$. Show that $\|g(x)\|\leq\lambda\|x\|$ for all $x\in B(\mathbf0,r)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is dealing with the fact that the range is $F$, a normed space.
This can be dealt with by using elements of the dual space $F^*$ to reduce the range to the underlying field, and by judicious use of the Hahn Banach theorem to 'return' to $F$.

Choose $\phi \in F^*$, and consider $h=\phi \circ g$. Note that $h$ is differentiable and $Dh(y)\delta = \phi(Dg(y)\delta)$.

Let $x \in B(0,r)$, then
$h (x) = h (0) + \int_0^1 Dh(tx) x\, dt$.
We have $h(0)=\phi (g (0)) = 0$, and 
$|Dh(tx) x|= |\phi(Dg(tx)x)| \le \|\phi\| \|Dg(tx)\| \|x\|\le \lambda \|\phi\| \|x\|$. Hence $|h(x)| = |\phi(g(x))| \le \lambda \|\phi\| \|x\|$.

Since this is true for all $\phi \in F^*$, we have $\|g(x)\| \le \lambda \|x\|$. To see this, define the functional $\eta$ on the line $L=\operatorname{sp} \{g(x)\}$ by $\eta(\alpha g(x)) = \alpha \|g(x)\|$. Note that the norm of $\eta$ on $L$ is $\|\eta\| = 1$. Then use the Hahn Banach theorem to extend $\eta$ to $F$ without increasing the norm (I use the same symbol $\eta$ for the extension, note that $\eta \in F^*$). Then we have $|\eta(g(x))| = \|g(x)\| \le \lambda \|x\|$, as required.

**Alternative approach**: Here is another approach that is a bit more tedious in detail:

Let $\epsilon>0$, and consider the function $\phi: [0,1] \to F$ defined by $\phi(t) = g(tx)$. Note that $\phi$ is differentiable, and $\phi'(t) = Dg(tx) x$. In particular, $\|\phi'(t)\| \le \lambda \|x\|$. By definition of the derivative, for each $t \in [0,1]$, there exists a $\delta_t>0$ such that if $|h|< \delta_t$ (and $t+h \in [0,1]$, of course) that $\|\phi(t+h)-\phi(t) - \phi'(t) h \| \le \epsilon |h|$. Since $\|a\|-\|b\| \le \|a-b\|$, we can write this as 
$\|\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)\| \le \|\phi'(t) h \| + \epsilon |h| \le (\lambda \|x\| + \epsilon) |h|$.

Now consider the open cover $\{B(t,\delta_t)\}$ of the compact domain $[0,1]$. There exists a finite subcover $\{ B(t_1, \delta_{t_1}) , ..., B(t_n, \delta_{t_n})\}$ (We can assume that the $t_i$ are strictly increasing). Hence we can find a collection of increasing points $\{ \tau_k \}_{k=1}^N \subset [0,1]$ such that $\tau_1 = 0$, $\tau_N = 1$, and each interval $[\tau_i, \tau_{i+1}]$ either starts or ends at some $t_j$, and $|\tau_i - \tau_{i+1}| < \delta_{t_j}$.

Then we have the estimate $\|\phi(1)-\phi(0) \| \le \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \|\phi(\tau_{k+1})-\phi(\tau_k) \| \le \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} (\lambda \|x\| + \epsilon) |\tau_{k+1}-\tau_k| = \lambda \|x\| + \epsilon$. Since $\phi(0) = 0, \phi(1) = g(x)$ and $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have the desired result.

**Addendum**: Explicit construction of the $\tau_k$.

Let $B_i = B(t_i, \delta_{t_i}) \cap [0,1]$.
Note that we can suppose the collection ${\cal O} = \{ B_1 , ..., B_n \}$ is 'not redundant' in the sense that if any single element is removed, the remaining sets no longer form a cover of $[0,1]$ (this is easy to do, if a set can be removed and the remaining sets are still a cover, then remove the set and repeat). Also, by renumbering if necessary, we can assume $0 \in B_1$, $1, \in B_n$. Furthermore, since the collection is 'not redundant', it is straightforward to show exactly one set contains $0$, and similarly for $1$.

We have tacitly assumed that $n>1$, otherwise we may choose $\tau_1 = 0, \tau_2 = t_1, \tau_3 = 1$, which satisfies the requirements.

Define a relation $\rightarrow$ on ${\cal O}$ as follows: $B_i \rightarrow B_j$ **iff** $B_i \cap B_j \neq \emptyset$ and $t_i<t_j$ (the centres). Consider the collection of 'paths' ${\cal P} = \{ (B_{j_1},...,B_{j_k}) | B_{j_1} = B_0, B_{j_i} \rightarrow B_{j_{i+1}}, i=1,..,k-1\}$. Note that since there are a finite number of $B_i$, and $B_i \rightarrow B_j$ (which implies $t_i<t_j$), the set ${\cal P}$ is finite.

If $(B_{j_1},...,B_{j_k}$ is a path, define $\sigma((B_{j_1},...,B_{j_k})) = \sup B_{j_k}$ (that is, the limit of points that can be 'reached' along that path).

Then I claim that $s = \max_{ (B_{j_1},...,B_{j_k}) \in {\cal P}} \sigma((B_{j_1},...,B_{j_k}) )  = 1$. To see this, suppose $s<1$, and let $\sigma((B_{j_1},...,B_{j_k}) )  = s$. Since the $B_i$ form a cover, we must have $s \in B_m = B(t_m,\delta_{t_m})$ for some $m$. So, we must have $B_{j_k} \cap B_m \neq \emptyset$. However, since $B_{j_k} \rightarrow B_m$ cannot be true (this would contradict the definition of $s$), we must have $t_m \le t_{k_j}$. However, this would contradict the fact the the collection is 'not redundant', hence we have $s=1$.

To finish, note that if $\sigma((B_{j_1},...,B_{j_k}) )  = 1$, we can assume that $B_{j_k} = B_n$ (if not, we can add $B_n$ to the path). Choose $u_i \in B_{j_i} \cap  B_{j_{i+1}}$ such that $t_{j_i} < u_i < t_{j_{i+1}}$ for $i=1,...,k-1$. Then the points $0,t_{j_1}, u_1, t_{j_2}, u_2,...,t_{j_k}, 1$ will satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Cooper be another way to test without using the Hahn Banach theorem? Is that in my course I have not yet studied analysis that theorem, I was thinking that maybe you can try the mean value theorem and some results related to this theorem

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: Well, you can, but you need to define integration of $F$ valued functions. If you haven't covered Hahn Banach, I am guessing that it is unlikely that you have covered integration of $F$ valued functions? Let me see if I can think of a more direct approach.

Comment: Yes Cooper have studied a bit of integration of F valued functions

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: Then you have $g(x) = g(0)+ \int_0^1 Dg(tx) x dt$, and you can estimate directly?

Comment: You need $\| \int f \| \le \int \|f \|$, of course.

Comment: I was thinking of a compactness based argument as an alternative, but the integral is a much prettier approach.

Comment: Sorry Cooper  I do not know how to estimate this integral

Comment: I will try to see if I can get a more direct approach later if I have time...

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: I added an argument that just depends on the definition and compactness.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Hello @copper.hat in yor construcrion of $\{\tau_k\}$ above how you get that $|\tau_i-\tau_{i+1}|<\delta_{t_j}$...studying achievement not build the collection that meets that condition .. can you help?

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: I will try to elaborate if I get a chance later. The construction is not difficult, just tedious to express.

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero: This has been bugging me all summer. I finally got a chance to write up the construction.